# Jest will not process import statement in typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, jestjs

I'm trying to run a basic test.

my source code is in src/index.ts with the following code:

```
    const sum = (a, b) => {return a+b}

    export default sum
```

and my test is in tests/index.test.ts with the following code:

```
    import sum from "./index";

test('adds 1 + 2 to equal 3', () => {
  expect(sum(1, 2)).toBe(3)
})
```

and when running npm run test which in package.json is set to test:"jest"
is giving me this error:

```
 ({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest){import sum from "./index";
                                                                                                    ^^^

    SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure you use [ts-jest](https://github.com/kulshekhar/ts-jest).

> ts-jest is a TypeScript preprocessor with source map support for Jest that lets you use Jest to test projects written in TypeScript.

Create a `jest.config.js` file in your project root directory and add this configuration:

```js
module.exports = {
  preset: 'ts-jest/presets/js-with-ts'
}
```